# Google Play services - version issue

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am targeting Android > 19. The latest Google Play services version is 5.2.08, but on my device the latest I can install is 4.4.52.

Now, when I check for `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` I always get that my version needs to be updated and I am redirected to the store. But I cannot update from strore, because the latest version is not supported on my device (I see only open and uninstall buttons).

What is the solution for this? I need only **notifications** feature, nothing more. Should I use older version of Play Services? How can I know which version to choose? Where to get the official older version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Android Studio, just replace in build.gradle :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

by

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89+'
```

or lower

Comment: Thank you that works. Do you know if there is any guarantee that it will work on any device with API 19+?

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this in your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+'
```

Try changing it to something like this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.+'
```